# How to configure mod_rewrite correctly while using CakePHP?

Tags: apache2, mod-rewrite

This at first might look like a duplicate question but I have done 10 hours of research on Internet and tried almost everything I've found but no luck with mod rewrite. Most of the post/tutorials on internet are old and they haven't updated their article since then.

I can see with `phpinfo()`, that I have successfully loaded the `mod_rewrite` module.

Next I know that I have to change `AllowOverride None` to `AllowOverride All` and few more changes on Apache's `default.conf` file. Since I don't have a `default.conf` file I did those changes on`000-default.conf`, but `mod_rewrite` doesn't work. I also changed the `apache.conf` file, it still didn't work. I changed all files where I can see `<Directory> </Directory>` but it didn't work.

My root directory is not `/var/www`, in fact it is `/var/www/html`.

Here is my `000-default.conf` file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
    # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
    # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
    # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
    # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
    # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
    # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
    #ServerName www.example.com

ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
DocumentRoot /var/www/html

# Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
# error, crit, alert, emerg.
# It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
# modules, e.g.
#LogLevel info ssl:warn

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

# For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
# enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
# include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
# following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
# after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
#Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf

 <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
 </Directory>

 <Directory /var/www>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow from All
 </Directory>

 <Directory /var/www/html>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from All
 </Directory>   
</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

How can I get `mod_rewrite` to work?

Comment: "Don't work" how? Throw an error? Doesn't do what you expect to do? What you expect it to do?

Comment: @Braiam, I expect my CakePHP (a PHP framework) to setup properly without this frustrating error.
"URL rewriting is not properly configured on your server"

Comment: Is it just me or is no mention of rewriting made in that file?

Comment: @muru which file you are talking about? be more clear. we can't chat in comments. so you gotta be more specific to decrease the number of comments.

Comment: @DarinPark considering you have posted only one file, I couldn't be more clear.

Comment: So, if I install Apache and download CakePHP (include that in your question!) I would have the same result as you?

Comment: Also note that if this is Apache 2.4, then instead if `Allow from`, I think you have to use `Require all granted`, etc. http://serverfault.com/a/549559

Comment: @muru I have tried that too after reading it somewhere but it didn't help.

Comment: @Braiam, so,how to solve that problem?

Comment: omg,I have been looking in the wrong direction all this time. I trusted too much on cakephp engine. I just created a new directory 'test' under `/var/www/html` and placed two files into it 'index.php' and 'index1.php' and then created a .htaccess file under that folder 'test' with content

`Options +FollowSymLinks
Options +Indexes
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^index.php$ index2.php [L]`

and it worked. So there must be some problem with CakePHP itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem Solved.It's a problem with CakePHP. .htaccess file of root directory was not getting copied alongside the cakePHP source.

Create a .htaccess file in your CakePHP root directory with this content

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
   RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10835344/cakephp-doesnt-work-url-rewriting-on-ubuntu